# Angular Injector error trying to use angular-gridify

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Got a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wozzo/b5z89kgg/3/)

I'm trying to use angular-gridify in a similar way to [this](http://homerjam.github.io/angular-gridify/), but I am getting an $injector error as below. How should I be injecting the angular-gridify dependency, assuming that's what the problem is?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'testApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl" ng-click="generateTiles()">
    <div class="gridify" ng-gridify="{wrapperSelector: '.wrapper', tileSelector: '.tile', perRow: 5, averageRatio: 1.5, gutter: 10, watch: 'tiles'}">
        <div class="wrapper">       
            <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" class="tile" data-ratio="{{tile.ratio}}" style="background-color: {{tile.color}}">
                <img src="{{tile.src}}"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-gridify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-gridify']).config(function() {});
testApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    })
});
testApp.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tiles = [];

    $scope.generateTiles = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            var ratio = Math.random() > 0.6 ? 0.661 : 1.511;
            $scope.tiles[i] = {
                ratio: ratio,
                color: '#' + ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6)
            };

        }
    };

    $scope.generateTiles();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your js you registered **testCtrl** controller instead of **ExampleCtrl** controller

Comment: Oops.Had changed it on the fiddle but didn't update it to testApp. It should reflect that now, and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I too have sometimes difficulties to get an Angular app running with JSFiddle. I took your code, modified it a little and put it in Codepen:

http://codepen.io/cgav/pen/QjweXe?editors=111

JS:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-gridify']);
testApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    })
});
testApp.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tiles = [];

    $scope.generateTiles = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            var ratio = Math.random() > 0.6 ? 0.661 : 1.511;
            $scope.tiles[i] = {
                ratio: ratio,
                color: '#' + ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6)
            };

        }
    };

    $scope.generateTiles();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div class="gridify" ng-gridify="{wrapperSelector: '.wrapper', tileSelector: '.tile', perRow: 5, averageRatio: 1.5, gutter: 10, watch: 'tiles'}">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" class="tile" data-ratio="{{tile.ratio}}" style="background-color: {{tile.color}}">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.tile {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
.tile > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

EDIT:
Keep in mind to include the references to angular-gridify and angular-route.

Comment: Without the css specifying height and width. Part of the function of the module is that it sets those properties for the justification to work correctly for images of different sizes.